# Binding extern NSString in Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, binding, xamarin.ios

I am currently working on a MobClix binding and I have come across this line:

```
extern NSString* const MCAdsErrorDomain;
```

That line appears outside any class or interface and I am not sure how to bind it in c#. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your definition looks C based so it should work just like Rolf's example tell you.

But if/when you're binding an Objective-C library using the `btouch` tool then you will want to use something like:

```
    [Field ("XXMyString")]
    NSString MyString { get; }
```

This is described in details in MonoTouch's binding [documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Binding_Fields).

Comment: This is exactly what I had before creating this topic, it doesn't compile because I don't know where to put it. The line of objective-c was outside of all classes and interface declarations. Can I put that field into any class?

Comment: In general (objective-c wise) the fields are documented with a specific type (where they are used) so that's where we bind them in MonoTouch. However since they are static you could add them anywhere it make sense (including a new type to hold them if you have several of them).

Comment: Would it be safest just to include the field in all classes, as I don't actually know where it will be used? Do I have to do anything other then [Field ()] to declare that it is a static field visible to all classes and interfaces?

Comment: `[Field]` should be enough. OTOH you can **skip** it until you **need** to use it. That way you'll be able to put it where it belongs (if you ever require it). IOW adding unused `[Field]` does not add any value to your bindings.

Answer (score 1):

It's done like this:

```
var handle = Dlfcn.dlopen ("/path/to/mobclix-library", 0);
NSString MCAdsErrorDomain = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant (handle, "MCAdsErrorDomain");
Dlfcn.dlclose (handle);
```

You can also see a sample here (which includes some error checking too): https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/CoreVideo/CVPixelFormatDescription.cs#L67